# Grails database checkboxes best practices to load and process

Tags: grails, checkbox

I have a collection of checkboxes loaded from a table that are loaded in a gsp (via a controller). Are there any best practices in grails to display them and process them once the form is submitted ? I wouldn't like to use the "manual" approach (i.e, composing the checkboxxes'id with the table row's id).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using indexed parameters, i.e.

```
<g:checkBox name="table[${index}].property" value="${tableInstance.property}" />
```

I've had some problems with that, and several solutions described in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574476/grails-checkbox-not-being-set-back-to-false). Note that that was in Grails 1.0.4 - it's possible that those problems have disappeared in recent versions.