# Grails hibernate many to many issue

Tags: hibernate, grails, instance

My Domain has a relationship as per this:

```
class Offices {

String officeLocation
String officeName

static belongsTo = Department
static hasMany = [departments:Department, employees:Employee]

}
```

When the user is on the page that allows them to add and remove location this is done by loading templates multiple times depending on the users choice. When the user hits "Add Location" I need to make sure the instance remains. My function in the controller:

```
def addLocation() {

def officesInstance = new Offices(officeLocation: params.officeLocation, officeName: params.officeName)

render template: "form" , model: [officesInstance: officesInstance]

}
```

view code:

```
<g:each var="entry" in="${departmentList}">

            <div class="control-group fieldcontain">
                <label class="bold" for="department">
                    <g:message code="department.locked.label" default="${entry.encodeAsHTML()}" />
                </label>
                <div class="controls form-field-align form-field-pad">
                    <g:checkBox name="department_${entry}" value="${officesInstance.value}" />
                </div>
            </div>

        </g:each>
```

The problem I'm having is I'm getting the following error when the addLocation function is pressed.

> | Error 2015-02-27 12:51:52,412 [http-bio-8080-exec-7]
>
> ERROR hibernate.AssertionFailure  - an assertion failure occured (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more likely due to unsafe use of the session)
>   Offices: null id in com.myapp.Offices entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
>
> Line | Method
>      200 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
>
> ---
>
> ```
> 63 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
> 53 | doFilter  in . grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter
> 49 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter
> 82 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter
> 1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
> 615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
> 745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
> ```
>
> | Error 2015-02-27 12:51:52,416 [http-bio-8080-exec-7]
>   ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - AssertionFailure occurred when processing request: [POST] /myapp/offices/addLocation - parameters:
>
> officeLocation: London
>
> formId: createForm
>
> elementToReplace: elementToReplace
>
> officeName: Office Name
>
> null id in com.smstool.Offices entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs). Stacktrace follows:
>   Offices: null id in com.myapp.Offices entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
>      Line | Method
>
> ```
> ->>  200 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> 63 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
> 53 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter
> 49 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter
> 82 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter
> 1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
> 615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
> 745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
> ```

Comment: you have forgot to save officesInstance.save(flush:true)

Comment: thanks.. that gets passed the issue of saving but my checkbox doesn't stay checked... updated above

Comment: what does ${officesInstance.value} return within your gsp if you just define this outside of the checkbox ?  I guess this be why its not working i.e. thats not the actual value of the checkbox being returned http://grails.asia/grails-checkbox-tag-example | http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/ref/Tags/checkBox.html

Comment: nothing, sorry that should just be officesInstance, it remains checked even if I've unchecked when adding another Location

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574476/grails-checkbox-not-being-set-back-to-false